# Create Batches from Object collection

Tags: c#

I have a collection of objects (more than 500 in count)
I would like to batch it with some logic, like a batch of 50's and I should get 10 sets.(10*50=500)

I am using the logic below:

```
 public class CustomEngineReader :IEnumerable<List<EngineToken>>
{
    StreamReader sr;
    int _batchSize = 1;

    public CustomFileReader(List<EngineToken> tokens, int batchSize)
    {
        if (batchSize > 0)
        {
            _batchSize = batchSize;
        }



    }


    public IEnumerator<List<string>> GetEnumerator()
    {

        string input = string.Empty;

        foreach(var item in EngineTokens)
        {
            int i = 0;
            List<string> batch = new List<string>();

            while (i < _batchSize && item !=null)
            {
                batch.Add(item );
                i++;
            }

            if (batch.Count != 0)
            {
                yield return batch;
            }
        }

    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I am using the above code as below

```
CustomEngineReader reader = new CustomEngineReader (this.tokencollection, 50);
foreach(List<EngineToken> items in reader)
{
       //in each iteration we get batch specified objects
       foreach(EngineToken item in items)
       {
          //Process
       }    
}
```

It's not working.

Comment: What about it isn't working?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I am not getting proper logic, its loading same set in all batches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a `while` loop inside of your `foreach` means that you're adding the same item over and over again until you hit your batch size.

You also need to create your `batch` object outside of the `foreach`, so that you can add multiple items from the loop into it.

Personally I prefer to write this as an extension method, rather than a separate class, to follow in line with the LINQ style of programming.  It also can be trivially made generic, greatly improving its usefulness.  My implementation of `Batch` is:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        buffer.Add(item);

        if (buffer.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (buffer.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this?

Comment: `var listOfBatches = list.Batch(batchSize);`  Or, as it often (but not always) works out to: `foreach(var batch in list.Batch(batchsize)){foreach(var item in batch){Process(item);}}`

Comment: I declared private IEnumerable<EngineToken> tokenCollection; tokenCollection.Batch??? It says can not find Batch!!, I know I am new to LINQ. kindly help.

Comment: @iShareHappyCode You'll need to ensure that there is a `using` for the namespace of the class that this method is in, for it to be found.

Comment: this method is in same class!!!, can u edit your above code to show the calling.? plz

Comment: Extension methods must be in a static class (you'll have gotten an error message indicating this to you).  The fact that you have instance fields means that the class is clearly not static.

Comment: Its working :) Thanks a lot for knowledge sharing. I wish to follow you.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding same item multiple times in a loop. Try:

```
public IEnumerator<List<EngineToken>> GetEnumerator()
{

    string input = string.Empty;

    int i=0;
    List<string> batch = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in EngineTokens)
    {
        batch.Add(item);
        i++;
        if(i==_batchSize)
        {
             yield return batch;
             batch = new List<string>();
             i = 0;
        }
    }
    if (batch.Count != 0)
    {
        yield return batch;
    }

}
```

Comment: Batch comes in different size by using above code:(

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simpler implementation, non-thread safe. For thread safety you will need to add locks as necessary.

```
public IEnumerator<List<EngineToken> GetEnumerator()
{    
        var currentBatch = EngineTokens.Take(_batchSize);
        EngineTokens = EngineTokens.Skip(_batchSize).ToList();
        return currentBatch;

}
```

Comment: 1) This won't even compile, as is.  You're returning a `List<EngineToken>` from a method that expects an `IEnumerator<List<EngineToken>>`.  2) Assuming you handle that, you never "end" the sequence.  You'll just continue providing empty batches once you run out of items.  (Either that or you only ever return the first batch, depending on how you fix issue #1. 3) It's enormously inefficient to take the time to copy every single item that hasn't yet been iterated to a new list on every batch.

Comment: Yes, I see the error; both of your concerns 1 & 2 can be fixed. This was meant to be algorithm rather than true code solution. If efficiency is a concern then it probably needs different algorithm.

Comment: The first two issues can be fixed, but it's not like they're just trivial little changes.  They're not just language syntax issues either.  They both represent algorithmic level flaws (as does the third, for that matter).